# Selecting top x from the sum of two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is formed like this
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE GREATEST(number, initial)
`| id | username | number | initial |`

I need to add the both top number and initial to retrieve the top.

Use this as an example

```
| id | username | number | initial | total
| 1  | a        | 665    | 441     | 1106
| 2  | b        | 918    | 99      | 1017
| 3  | c        | 611    | 336     | 947
| 4  | d        | 491    | 968     | 1459
| 5  | e        | 414    | 129     | 543
```

What I need is to retrieve the highest number first and the lowest number last.

I have tried `SELECT * FROM`test`WHERE GREATEST(number, initial)` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I'm not so experienced with SQL, but one thing I have tried is this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the record with the highest value of number + initial:

```
select * from test
order by (number + initial) desc
limit 1
```

or, if you want all records that have the greatest value of number + initial:

```
select * from test
where test.number + test.initial = 
    (select max(test.number + test.initial)
    from test)
```

or, if you want to order all records by the value of number + initial in descending order:

```
select * from test
order by (number + initial) desc
```

Comment: The last one I think I needed, that's it?! I thought it was more complicated. Thank you very much.